# Is the pressure zero in thermal equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, ideal-gas, equilibrium

In a canonical ensemble, we have $dU=TdS-pdV$. When we are in equilibrium, the energy $U$ is [minimized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_minimum_energy). This implies that $\left(\frac{dU}{dV}\right)_S=0$. Since $\left(\frac{dU}{dV}\right)_S=-p$, we get $-p=0$, so $p=0$. However, this seems to be wrong. For example, putting $p=0$ in the Ideal Gas Law we get $pV=nRT=0$, so the temperature is $0$ as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See my answer to this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/445091/thermodynamics-second-law-variational-statement-query/445129#445129

Answer (score 1):

The thermodynamic potential associated with the canonical ensemble is the free energy $F = U - TS$ . So I will continue about free energy. In order for the system to be in thermodynamic equilibrium, we need to fix the external conditions. For the so-called simple systems in the canonical ensemble, we fix $T$, $V$, $N$ as external conditions. Fixed external conditions do not exclude thermal motion inside the thermodynamic system. So even with fixed $T$, $V$, $N$, there are, let's call them internal, fluctuations within the system. For example, these may be local density fluctuations that are different at different points in the system, $\rho(\vec{r})$. It is clear that the actual value of the free energy of the system, $F_{fact}$ depends on the local density. Basically, we can write this actual value as a functional $F_{fact}[\rho(\cdot)]$. And when we say that the free energy of the system is minimal in thermodynamic equilibrium, we mean that the thermodynamic, it is also equilibrium, value of $F$ is the minimum value of the functional $F_{fact}[\rho(\cdot)]$ with respect to internal fluctuations of $\rho$. So, there is no extremum of $F_{fact}$ with respect to *fixed* external parameters, $T$, $V$, $N$.

By the way, the equation expressing the extremum of $F_{fact}$ with respect to density fluctuations $\rho(\vec{r})$ is
$$
\frac{\delta F_{fact}}{\delta\rho(\vec{r})} = \lambda = const \quad \forall \vec{r}
$$
On the right side of this equation there is some constant, not zero, because of the fixed $N$ and $V$. From this equation follows the equality of pressure at all points within the system.

As for the equality $dF = -SdT - pdV + \mu dN$, it expresses a change in thermodynamic, that is, equilibrium, free energy under changing external conditions. From this equality follows
$$
p = -\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}\right)_{T,N}
$$
but
$$
-p = \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}\right)_{T,N} = 0
$$
does not follow from anywhere.

Comment: . However, I think you should probably explain better the reason for the introduction of $\lambda$.

Comment: How does this answer the question? See the link I've added.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I don't see the links you added in this thread. You just edited the question.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 $\lambda$ is a Lagrange multiplier. It occurs because of the condition $\int_V\rho(\vec{r}) d\vec{r} = M$.

Comment: I linked the word "minimize".

Comment: @TobiasFünke Oh, I overlooked that. However, I think I have tried to answer this question. Do you think that my answer is completely useless given the large amount of text to which you have given a link?

Comment: As far as I interpret OP's question, they ask the following: The principle of minimum energy states, following Wikipedia, that at equilibrium $\partial_X U=0$ (constant $S$). For the particular case in the question this seems to imply that $p=0$. I don't see how you answered that question here, but I might miss something (perhaps obvious?). I have the impression, though, that the Wikipedia article is a bit sloppy at some points... But again, I might be completely off...

Comment: In particular, the importance of a closed vs an isolated system (as actually pointed out in the beginning of the article) is important here. And I guess if one does all of this properly, considering two systems with some unconstrained variables, then the equilibrium condition $p_1=p_2$ will follow.

Comment: @TobiasFünke It is quite possible that my answer is not formulated well enough. But the statement that $dU/dV = 0$ due to the minimum of energy is obviously incorrect. I think the author has some kind of misconception about this matter, which I have tried to correct.

Comment: I could guess the meaning of $\lambda$. My comment was intended as an invitation to clarify this point in the text of your question. You have to take into account that questions and answers remain. Comments may be canceled.

Answer (score 0):

A system happily expands if you let it; condensed matter evaporates, and the gaseous state fills the available volume. The path to equilibrium progresses asymptotically toward infinite volume, zero pressure, zero temperature, maximum entropy, and minimum energy. If you started with an ideal gas, the total extracted work is $nc_VT$, where $c_V$ is the constant-pressure molar heat capacity. If you started with compressed condensed matter, you could also recover the strain energy, less the cost of the phase change(s).

Answer (score 0):

I think that my misconception was about the meaning of ‘minimized energy’. Apparently, the energy is not minimized with respect to everything, but only with respect to certain variables. In particular, it is not minimized with respect to $S,V,N,\mu,T,p$.